# How do I do a join in ActiveRecord after records have been returned?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3, activemodel

I am using ActiveRecord in Rails 3 to pull data from two different tables in two different databases.  These databases can not join on each other, but I have the need to do a simple join after-the-fact.  I would like to preserve the relation so that I can chain it down the line.

here is a simplified version of what I am doing

```
browsers = Browser.all # <-- this is fairly small and can reside in memory
events = Event.where(:row_date=>Date.today).select(:name, :browser_id)
```

So as you can see, I want to join `browsers` in on the `events` relation, where `browser_id` should equal `browsers.name`. `events` is a relation and I can still add clauses to it down the line, so I dont want to run the query on the db just yet.  How would I accomplish this?

***Edit***

For those that would like to see some code for the answer I accepted below, here is what I came up with:

```
class EventLog < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :browser

  def get_todays_events
    Event.where(:row_date=>Date.today).select(:name, :browser_id).includes(:browser)
  end
end
```

would let me get the browser name in the following manner

```
get_todays_events.browser.name
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would accomplish this by using an :include. Attempting to do this in Ruby will cause you nothing but grief. You can chain onto an include just fine.

Comment: hmm, it seems the new rails does the join in memory rather than building it into the sql query.  thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

`joins` does create SQL joins as expected in the current Rails 5:

`` pry(main)> Customer.joins(:orders).limit(5)
  Customer Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  `customers`.* FROM `customers` INNER JOIN `orders` ON `orders`.`customer_id` = `customers`.`id` LIMIT 5
=> [#<Customer:0x007fb869f11fe8
... ``

This should be vastly faster, because it only requires a single database query, whereas `includes` will perform `1 + <number of rows in first table> + <number of rows in second table>...`

Here's an example where `includes` requires 1750x as long as `joins`:

```
pry(main)> benchmark do
   Order.joins(:address, :payments, :customer, :packages).all.size
> 0.02456 seconds

pry(main)> benchmark do
[14] pry(main)* Order.includes(:address, :payments, :customer, :packages).all.map(&:zip).max
[14] pry(main)*end
=> 35.607257 seconds
```